# JS Как зная класс элемента получить его id в переменную?

Tags: javascript

Как на JavaScript зная класс элемента получить его id

```
<span id="idelement" class="classelement">ТЕСТ</span>
```

Пробовал так но здесь я получаю наоборот класс а мне нужен id

```
var result = window.content.document.getElementById("idelement").className;
alert(result);
```

Comment: См. [getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). Само собой, вы получите коллекцию из всех элементов с данным классом.

Comment: @PinkTux Получается нужно так? Я в Java не очень.

var result = document.getElementsByClassName("classelement").getElementById();

Записал не правильно, уже понял. Но как получить id зная его клас я всеравно не понял

Comment: JavaScript не Java! См. ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

См. [getElementsByClassName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp). На выходе получится коллекция элементов, так как, в отличие от `id`, класс элемента не уникален, и в документе может быть сколько угодно элементов с данным классом. Использование:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) 
{
    alert( elements[i].id );
}
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое.